# Parsing Date that is read from file

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have record in the file as `17 Dec 2010 17:02:24 17 Dec 2010 18:02:24`. I am reading these from file....
my parser code is:

```
static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");

public static String DateFormat(String startdate) {

    String date = null;
    try {

        java.util.Date tDate = df.parse(startdate);

        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
        String formatteddate = df.format(tDate).toUpperCase();

        return formatteddate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to Parse" + e);
    }
    return date;

}
```

but only first date format get parsed...then error will be *unable to parse*

Answer (score 2):

you are over writing the `df` value again with a different format (as shown below) in the `DateFormat(...)` method. df is a static variable so it will use this new format for sub sequent reads. **Use a new local variable** for "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a"

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: @above...this will chenge the format...if include "SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");" inside the function all records will be read...but it should be kept outside to prevent repeated creation of df..

Comment: @panega...even if create local variable...i still have the error

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
static SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
static SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");

    public static String getFormattedDate(String startdate) {

    String date = null;
    try {

        java.util.Date tDate = inputDateFormat.parse(startdate);

        String formatteddate = outputDateFormat.format(tDate).toUpperCase();

        return formatteddate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to Parse" + e);
    }
    return date;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're re-using `df` as Pangea stated.

```
static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");

public static String DateFormat(String startdate) {

    String date = null;
    try {

        java.util.Date tDate = df.parse(startdate);

        SimpleDateFormat outputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
        String formatteddate = outputDf.format(tDate).toUpperCase();

        return formatteddate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to Parse" + e);
    }
    return date;

}
```